# How can I change a specific character at the start of a verseline?

Tags: characters, verse

I use the package verse. I need to change specific characters at the start of a verse. E.g. if the verse is starting with A, it should be transformed to \hspace*{1mm}BA.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{verse}

\begin{document}
\begin{verse}
This is a verse.\\
Another verse.
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

I need a new command which prints the verses and changes the prescribed occurences at the start of a verseline.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide us with a minimal, compilable example to help us help you.

Comment: You would need another macro to parse the text one letter at a time and search for \ifnextchar A while \ifvmode.

Comment: How can I parse the text? As a string?